# Connect to cassandra inside docker from other server

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have two instances on AWS EC2. In one of the instance I have installed Cassandra inside docker.

Now I want to connect to cassandra from another AWS instance. 
Can someone help me to do it.

I found this link https://github.com/nicolasff/docker-cassandra/issues/5
But not working for me.

Comment: How did you start your cassandra DB? Mapped its port to the port of your aws instance + opened it?

Comment: I cloned like `docker pull cassandra` then run `docker run -it --name=cas -d cassandra`  So cassandra is already running

Comment: I'm not that experienced with cassandra but maybe try this: `docker run -it --name=cas -p 9042:9042 -d cassandra` this will map the container-port 9042 on the port of your server (I would think you try to connect on that port?). Then edit your security group of your ec2 instance that the server (with your application) is allowed to connect on that port on your ec2 instance.

Answer (score 2):

lvthillo's comment would work. The Cassandra should expose the port to the node. So other node could access it.

Another note: if container restarts, Cassandra data will be lost. You should at least mount the node's local directory into container. `docker run --name some-cassandra -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/cassandra -p 9042:9042 -d cassandra`